Compilation error in file lib/phoenix/live_dashboard/page_builder.ex after a fresh install
When I want to install a new Elixir project with: mix phx.new foo and then try to start my Phoenix app with mix phx.server I get the following error message:
== Compilation error in file lib/phoenix/live_dashboard/page_builder.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Macro.expand_literals/2 is undefined or private. Did
  * expand/2
  * expand_literal/2

Whole error message: https://pastebin.pl/view/8850c592
I never got this message before and reinstalled Elixir, but it remains.
The following suggestion in the error message doesn't help either:
u can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile phoenix_live_dashboard", update it with "mix depshoenix_live_dashboard" or clean it with "mix deps.clean phoenix_live_dashboard"

Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.1.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]
Elixir 1.14.0 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 24)
Update / Workaround
I installed asdf, installed elixir and Erlang via asdf as the follows: asdf install elixir latest; asdf install erlang latest and exported MIX_HOME="$HOME/.mix" and MIX_ARCHIVES="$MIX_HOME/archives".

Getting the same issue from y'day
